# How to use Azure application insights with nextjs app

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-application-insights

I want to use Azure app insight with nextjs but unable to do it , can anyoe help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use azure app insight with nextjs by using the default react plug-in and you have to create your own history object for nextjs , after the page loads you can make that history object = window.history object. after that you can initiate app insight with the help of that history object . This will solve your problem. I wrote an article regarding the same and you can see this link for refernce.
https://medium.com/@nirbhayluthra/integrating-azure-application-insights-with-next-js-the-easy-way-afc83596afad

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use Azure app insight with nextjs but unable to do it , can anyoe help me with that?

You can use [`next-applicationinsights`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-applicationinsights) (package created by [goenning](https://github.com/goenning)) to automatically track page views, dependency calls, and exceptions on your Next.js applications by using Azure Application Insights, try following installation step and code snippet from [`next-applicationinsights`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-applicationinsights):

**Installation:**

```
npm install next-applicationinsights
```

**Example:**

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'
import { withApplicationInsights } from 'next-applicationinsights';
 
class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
 
    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
 
export default withApplicationInsights({ 
  instrumentationKey: 'YOUR_KEY_GOES_HERE',
  isEnabled: true //process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
})(MyApp)
```

You can refer to [Application Insights Usage with NextJS](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/977) , [Enabling the Node.js Application Insights SDK in Next.js](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/enabling-the-node-js-application-insights-sdk-in-next-js-746762d92507) and [How to use the library with Nextjs?](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/808)

Answer (score 1):

From the version 13.4.14 NextJS creates multiple processes for routing, page rendering etc. And appInsights setup needs to be implemented in the instrumentation hook.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation

Here is an usage example https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-opentelemetry

Comment: I looked in to the above example. But I don't know where to setup the app insights connection string in the application.

Comment: Did anyone recently tried integrating Azure App Insights with Next.js 13.x app? How things have changed for integration?

Answer (score 0):

Create ApplicationInsightsService.js file like this:

```js
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
import { ReactPlugin } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js';

const reactPlugin = new ReactPlugin();
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    connectionString: 'instrumentationKey=your-key',
    extensions: [reactPlugin],
    enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
    disableAjaxTracking: false,
    autoTrackPageVisitTime: true,
    enableCorsCorrelation: true,
    enableRequestHeaderTracking: true,
    enableResponseHeaderTracking: true,
  },
});
appInsights.loadAppInsights();

appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer((env) => {
  env.tags = env.tags || [];
  env.tags['ai.cloud.role'] = 'testTag';
});

export { reactPlugin, appInsights };
```

wrap your app.js / layout.js file with provider:

```js
export default function Layout({ children, params: { lang } }) {
  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <body>
        <AppInsightsContext.Provider value={reactPlugin}>
          {children}
        </AppInsightsContext.Provider>          
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

To track custom events:

```js
import {
  useAppInsightsContext,
  useTrackEvent,
} from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js';

export default function Message() {
 const appInsights = useAppInsightsContext();
 const trackSendMessageEvent = useTrackEvent(
   appInsights,
   'send_message_event',
   { message: '' },
   true,
 );

 const sendMessage = () => {
   trackSendMessageEvent({ message: 'updated message' });
 }

  return (
    <button onClick={sendMessage}>sendMessage</button>
  );
}
```